# Why is the blood money of a woman half that of a man in Islam?

Tags: sharia, women, diyya

There is no strict verse in the Qur'an which clearly shows us that the blood money of a women is half that of a man.  However, narrations both in Shi'ite and Sunni traditions exist regarding this case. For instance, Imam Sadiq(a.s) says that,

> دیة المرأة نصف دیة الرجل>
>
> (وسائل الشیعه، ج 19، ص 151. نشر دارلاحیا التراث العربی، بیروت، بی تا.)

Another Sunni narration says that woman's blood money is half of man's:

> (کنز العمال، ج 15، ص 57. نشر دارالاحیا التراث العربی، بیروت، بی تا .)

Now my question is, why the woman's blood money is such? in other words what is the reasoning behind this judgment?

Sources:

- Vasel Al Shiah by Shekh Hor Ameli
- Kanz al Ummal

Answer (score 1):

### When is blood money applied?

- Blood money is **not a price** for the person killed; it is a **financial compensation** for the harm caused to the family of the victim, to be paid by the killer if the death was accidental, or not intentional.

### why the blood money of a Women is half of the blood money of a man in Islam?

- because the financial loss to the family by the demise of a male member is greater compared to the loss of the female member.

### Does this imply value of women is less than that of men?

- No, because

  1. blood money is financial compensation, NOT the body-price of the deceased
  2. in case of planned murder, the killer is punished by death, regardless of the gender of the killer and the killed.

---

SOURCE: [Why Is a Woman's Blood Money Half a Man's?](http://www.onislam.net/english/ask-the-scholar/acts-of-worship/zakah/misconceptions/169675.html) and [Blood Money](http://womeninislam.ws/en/misconceptions_blood-money.aspx)

NB: [Iranian women get equal 'blood money'](http://www.alarabiya.net/articles/2008/05/27/50520.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to add to the other good answer:

In the case of the unintentional death of one person among a husband and a wife, who receives the financial compensation? The other one. That is: A wife receives twice as much financial compensation a husband would receive.

So this rule of Islam is absolutely concerning women, and absolutely logical.

This rule is about any unintentional causing of a death, and not necessarily containing criminal recklessness or negligence(unlike the legal definition of "Unintentional Manslaughter" in the western law). So it acts like a life insurance.